# Autoscroll on pagerAdapter only in the first window

Tags: java, android, adapter, autoscroll

I have a problem with this code, I have no more ideas for. I need when the user is in the window 0 and open window 1, the window 0 autoscroll to window 1. I need this only works in the first window. (window 0 -> open window 1- autoscroll 0 to 1)

```
public void onNewConversation(String target)
  {
      createNewConversation(target);

  int position = pagerAdapter.getPositionByName(target);

    if (position ==  0) {

              pager.setCurrentItem(pagerAdapter.getPositionByName(target) - 1);
              pager.setCurrentItem(1);
      }

}
```

Comment: What do mean by *window*? Activity? List item? ...can you be more explicit, please.

Comment: The window is the screen, the target...